# Black screen after installing Ubuntu Gnome 15.04

Tags: gnome, system-installation, 15.04

I decided to switch from Windows to Linux and therefore don't have much experience with the OS.

I tried installing the latest version of Ubuntu Gnome and chose the option to wipe Windows completely. The installation went well and I got a message which said that the everything would be usable after a quick restart. Problem is, when I try to boot my computer it just flashes the logo of the laptop's manufacturer (like it does everytime) and then just shows a black screen. There is no input option. Just a black screen.

I don't know what I should do now, accessing the grub menu doesn't work (I already tried pressing shift, esc or c) and therefore can't do anything.

The only specs I know about my laptop without looking them up (which I can't right now) is that it's 32 bit, has 2gb ram and uses an AMD graphics card.

Edit: I just realized that you could look that up via BIOS. So, uh, I hope that's useful enough. http://www.i.imgur.com/ABl5PCwh.jpg/

Would be absolutely great if someone could help me! (especially since it's the only laptop I can use) Thanks!